# Randomizing MAC address on startup in Linux Mint

Tags: linux, debian, networking, scripting

I’d like Linux Mint to randomize my MAC address on startup on all network interfaces (`enp2s0f1` & `wlp3s0`), and notify me if one of them failed to change via a pop-up.

How would I go about doing this?

(I’m running Linux Mint 18.1 64-bit)

Comment: are you using network manager/wicd/etc or do you connect via /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: @ivanivan I’m connecting via network-manager

Comment: +1 Been thinking myself of doing that, but have not looked how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

A more standard way to randomize MAC addresses is using `macchanger`.

Following (roughly) the instructions of the ubuntu wiki: [AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AnonymizingNetworkMACAddresses)

> Install MACCHANGER
>
> The package macchanger is in the Networking
> (universe). Install it.
>
> ```
> apt-get install macchanger
> ```
>
> Create the Randomizer Trigger
>
> Utilizing Network-Manager's methods to trigger events when a network
> interface changes state, place the macchanger script into
> `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`.
>
> ```
> vi /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger
> ```
>
> Don't change $IFACE. It is a
> reference provided by NetworkManager for the particular activated
> interface.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Randomize the mac address for the given interface 
> /usr/bin/macchanger -e "$IFACE"
> ```
>
> Make it executable.
>
> ```
> chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger
> ```
>
> Interface State Change
>
> Now everytime any managed interface is activated, as it passes through
> the pre-up phase, the network MAC address will be randomized under the
> VENDOR id.
>
> Fully Random
>
> If you desire a completely random MAC address change the
> -e in the macchanger script to -r.

Comment: I have cut steps from the original page, as they are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’ll try it out and let you know if it worked or not :)

Comment: I've encountered a problem, but don't know where to post it, as the explanation is a bit long. I'll do my best to explain myself.

Comment: I went to create the /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger file, but it tuns out it already existed, and had content in it (I have no idea why). Here is what it had:

Comment: #!/bin/sh
#
# randomize MAC address before connecting to wifi or ethernet
#
# This script should always be run in if-pre-up.d, but unfortunately
# NetworkManager does not run if-pre-up.d scripts before it sets up a network
# connection (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=387832).
# if-post-down.d scripts are run, so there is a symlink to this script
# there. That means when running network config from the terminal, macchanger
# will be run twice, but it'll only be run in if-post-down.d when using
# NetworkManager.

(continues)

Comment: package=macchanger

. /etc/default/${package}

LOGFILE=/var/log/${package}.log

if [ "$ENABLE_ON_POST_UP_DOWN" != "true" ]; then
    echo "disabled in /etc/default/${package}" >> $LOGFILE
    exit
fi

echo "IFACE = $IFACE" >> $LOGFILE

# quit if we're called for the loopback
if [ "$IFACE" = lo ]; then
    echo "ignoring loopback" >> $LOGFILE
    exit 0
fi

/usr/bin/${package} -e $IFACE >> $LOGFILE 2>&1

Comment: it turns out there is a symlink between this file and another, here is the ls -l output:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  344 Mar 14  2016 ethtool

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Feb 10  2015 macchanger -> ../../macchanger/ifupdown.sh

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3839 May  3  2012 wireless-tools

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Mar 25  2017 wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh

Comment: Sorry to post all of this mumbo jumbo, but I didn't know where else to post it, and formatting in comments is very poor. Thank you so much for your help :)